Improving Data Tracking with 'Crawl Once' Filter in Scrapy
I’m using the 'crawl once' filter in Scrapy to avoid scraping the same link more than once, which helps reduce overall proxy usage. Is there a way to adjust the middleware so that, when 'crawl once' is active and detects a previously scraped listing, it can still yield the UID and ScrapeTime for that listing? If not, that's okay, but I’m hoping to improve data tracking on the backend.
Thank you!
I tried to create a custom 'crawl once' middleware, but we can't yield or return anything from middleware.

Welcome, Zubair Shahzad. Some code attached would be faster to find necessary ones.

I think you can write your crawled link and ScrapyTime to a redis by your custom middleware, so you can search a crawling link from redis to make sure that it has not been crawled yet. Besides scrapy-redis could help you doing it that way simply.
